# Fork between GitHub and GitLab projects

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Is it possible to fork a GitHub project into a GitLab project and the other way around?

Comment: https://george.autonomic-networks.ele.tue.nl/fork-from-github-to-gitlab/

Comment: Article is gone :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When creating a new repository, you can choose to import another repository, and one of the options is to import it via its `https://...` url from another repository site, such as github. This starts a `git clone --bare <url>` to import the repository. In the [GitLab documentation](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/12/01/how-to-keep-your-fork-up-to-date-with-its-origin/) the process is described in detail. Whenever I tried that, the process kept refreshing to the same "in progress" state indefinetly.

> *Update:* This seems to work only for repositories you own. So to import a public repository, a workaround would be to fork it and import the fork.

So another way would be to clone the repository on the commandline before populating your new repository:

When you create a new, empty repository at your gitlab site, you get a page full of suggestions how to proceed to populate this repository.
Setting up a tracker for a github site is basically a variant of the 
**Existing Git repository** recipe with the minor difference of cloning the repository to track first, and instead of renaming the previous `origin` to  `old-origin` as suggested in the recipe, you want to rename it to `upstream` instead to maintain conventions. So you'll end up with proceedings as outlined:

1. Clone the original repository you want to track:

   `git clone https://github.com/<author>/<repository.git> <repository>-tracker`
2. Change into the directory the repository was cloned into

   `cd <repository>-tracker`
3. rename the source (`origin`) to something else (`upstream`), so you can still address it. 

   `git remote rename origin upstream`
4. create your own repository located at your gitlab server, giving it a suitable name and description (don't miss to reference/link the original source there)
5. add the url of your own gitlab repository as `origin`. The exact line to use including the path to your own repository can be found in the **Existing Git repository** recipe you probably received as a result of the previous step.

   `git remote add origin git@<gitlab-server>/<path-to-your-repo>.git`
6. push the repository to your gitlab server:

   `git push -u origin --all
   git push -u origin --tags`
7. afterwards:

   `git remote -v
   origin   git@<gitlab-server>/<path-to-your-repo>.git (fetch)
   origin   git@<gitlab-server>/<path-to-your-repo>.git (push)
   upstream     https://github.com/<author>/<repository.git> (fetch)
   upstream     https://github.com/<author>/<repository.git> (push)`

Comment: First method looks to work now (2023/08)